# Curl command line works, C++ curl library does not

Tags: c++, c, json, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to do some request via curl library of C++. I can **successfully** do my request and get the correct response via **command line**, but I cannot get the correct response via **C++ code**. My command line command looks like this

```
curl -X POST -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: <some_hash_value>' -k <my_full_url> -data '<my_json_string>'
```

That works fine. Now I try to do the same request in C++ code. My code looks like this

```
void performRequest(const std::string& json, const void* userData, CallbackFunction callback)
{
    struct curl_slist* headers = NULL;

    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, (std::string("Authorization: ") + m_authorization).c_str());

    CURL* curlHandle = curl_easy_init();
    if (!curlHandle)
    {
        std::cerr << "Curl handler initialization failed";
    }

    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

    // specify target URL, and note that this URL should include a file name, not only a directory
     curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, m_url.c_str());

    // enable uploading
    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);

    // set HTTP method to POST
    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

    // set json data; I use EXACTLY the same string as in command line
    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS, json.c_str());

    // set data size
    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE, json.size());

    // set user data for getting it in response
    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, userData);    // pointer to a custom struct

    // set callback function for getting response
    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callback);    // some callback

    // send request
    curl_easy_perform(curlHandle);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curlHandle);
    curl_slist_free_all(headers);
}
```

However, for some reason I get an error in the response from the server, from which I can assume that my code's request is not equivalent to command line's command. It seems that body is not sent. I cannot see my request Json body when I use CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION for dumping debug info.

What is the problem here? What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have wireshark diagnostics available?

Comment: I'm afraid - no, I don't have.

Comment: You should remove `curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE, json.size());`. If the size has not been set prior to CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS, the data is assumed to be a zero terminated string; else the stored size informs the library about the byte count to copy. In any case, the size must not be changed after CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS, unless another CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS or CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS option is issued. See: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS.html

Comment: Since you get a response from the server that could be very useful. Look at https://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: @Rocki I've tried to remove that line and also tried to exchange lines of `CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS` and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE` options, but result was the same...

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe it looks like they don't have an install package for linux and I have to build is from source code, right?

Comment: @nabroyan No you have it in your package manager as `wireshark`.

Comment: What if you get rid of both `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` and `CURLOPT_UPLOAD` as these are not needed for this request?  Does it work?

Comment: According to the curl API documentation for CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST --> When you change the request method by setting CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST to something, you don't actually change how libcurl behaves or acts in regards to the particular request method, it will only change the actual string sent in the request. So perhaps you need to look at CURLOPT_POST first and see if you can get your body to send.

Comment: I have a different question here. `CURLcode curl_easy_setopt(CURL *handle, CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS, char *data);` requires a `char *` where `std::string c_str()` will provide `const char*`. How did you get around without using a `const_cast` in first place?

Comment: Guys, the problem was solved! I have removed the lines for setting `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARG`, `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST`, `CURLOPT_UPLOAD` and `CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL`. Also note that `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARG` can work if it is set before setting CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS.
Please write an answer that I can accept it.

Comment: @nabroyan You can write the answer yourself and accept it...

Comment: @Rocki drew010 please post your answers that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved tanks to [Rocki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6072633/rocki)'s and [drew010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/892493/drew010)'s comments.

1. I have removed `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST`, `CURLOPT_UPLOAD` and `CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL` setting statements as there is no need of them.
2. I have also removed the line for setting `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE`, although it works fine if it is set before setting `CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS`.
   If the size has not been set prior to `CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS`, the data is assumed to be a zero terminated string; else the stored size informs the library about the byte count to copy. In any case, the size must not be changed after `CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS`, unless another `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` or `CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS` option is issued. (See: [curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS.html](http://You%20should%20remove%20curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle,%20CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE,%20json.size());.%20If%20the%20size%20has%20not%20been%20set%20prior%20to%20CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS,%20the%20data%20is%20assumed%20to%20be%20a%20zero%20terminated%20string;%20else%20the%20stored%20size%20informs%20the%20library%20about%20the%20byte%20count%20to%20copy.%20In%20any%20case,%20the%20size%20must%20not%20be%20changed%20after%20CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS,%20unless%20another%20CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS%20or%20CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS%20option%20is%20issued.%20See:%20curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS.html))

Comment: Could the answer be rephrased someway to emphazise on what was wrong rather than "I did a bunch of stuff and then it works"?

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample code that should work for you.

Notice that I:

- Removed `CURLOPT_UPLOAD` as it does not seem as you are actually uploading something but rather just doing a simple `POST`.
- Changed `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` to `CURLOPT_POST` (not that it should matter), but I find it cleaner.
- Reordered `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE` and `CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS`
- Removed the `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` line for the sake of this sample code.

I have tested the following only by connecting to an instance of `nc -l localhost 80`

> ```
>  static size_t callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
>  {
>    string s(ptr);
>    cout << s << endl;
>    return size * nmemb;
>  }
>
>
>  int main(int argc, char** argv)
>  {
>    string m_authorization("PWNED");
>    string m_url("http://localhost");
>    string m_json("{}");
>
>    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
>
>    CURL* curlHandle = curl_easy_init();
>
>    struct curl_slist* headers = nullptr;
>    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");
>    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
>    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, (std::string("Authorization: ") + m_authorization).c_str());
>
>    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
>    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
>
>    // specify target URL, and note that this URL should include a file name, not only a directory
>    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, m_url.c_str());
>
>    // <= You are not uploading anything actually, this is a simple POST with payload
>    // enable uploading
>    // curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);
>
>    // set HTTP method to POST
>    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
>
>    // set data size before copy
>    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE, m_json.size());
>
>    // set json data; I use EXACTLY the same string as in command line
>    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS, m_json.c_str());
>
>    // set user data for getting it in response
>    // curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, userData);    // pointer to a custom struct
>
>    // set callback function for getting response
>    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callback);    // some callback
>
>    // send request
>    curl_easy_perform(curlHandle);
>
>    curl_slist_free_all(headers);
>
>    curl_easy_cleanup(curlHandle);
>    curl_global_cleanup();
>    return 0;
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

In windows, you must init the winsock stuff with below function

```
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
```